# Como acomodar una imagen con css?

Tags: html, css, css3

El problema es que la imagen se baja unos pixeles de donde deberia de estar,
es decir la franja superior roja NO deberia de verse.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  background: #DDDFE2; }

section {
  background: 100%;
  height: 400px; }
.main_bus {
  background-size: 30%;
  position: relative; }
  .main_bus .layout_center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left: 80px;
    width: calc(100% - (70px + 70px)); }
    .flex_content {
            display: flex; }

          .flex_column {
            flex: 1;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: .4em; }
            .flex_column img {
              padding-top: .4em; }
            .flex_column div {
              padding-top: .4em; }
          .height_250px{
            height: 250px;
          }
          .height_350px{
            height: 350px;
          }
          .height_270px{
            height: 270px;
          }
          .height_450px{
            height: 450px;
          }
          .height_300px{
            height: 300px;
          }
          .height_560px{
            height: 560px;
          }
          .card{
            background: transparent;
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
            
          }
          .card > .front,
          .card > .back {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            position: absolute;
            transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
            transition-duration: 1s;
            transition-property: transform, opacity;
            border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
            background:red;
          }
          .front{
            top:0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 1;
          }
          .front > img{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
          }
          .back{
            background: #fcfabc;
            top:0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
            transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          }
          .card:hover > .front {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            opacity: 0;
          }
          .card:hover > .back {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
          }
```

```html
<section class="main_bus" id="inicio">
            
            <div class="layout_center">
                <div class="flex_content">
                  <div class="flex_column">
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_560px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/9a/a9/f0/9aa9f0235a64eb5f123402efcacb5197.jpg" alt="">  
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_270px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/fa/84/09/fa840965a10cb0c28410d06e5087978a.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_250px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/e9/2b/c3/e92bc328087ee008adf4eee9411e8a4c.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_300px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/93/8f/56/938f564ca79e20fe54cb42df44b1c150.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex_column">
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_250px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6c/61/d2/6c61d2afbe1551435f2e858365465cbd.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_350px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/8c/fa/06/8cfa06657b77435e91c3466f15319ebb.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_450px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/3a/a8/51/3aa8513f2d9fde7a97e83a891aa64a73.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_270px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/ed/00/75/ed0075587fdeeed877c0aab2a23572c5.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

La parte mas especifica es:

```
  .front > img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  }
```

Alguien sabe como solucionar este problema?

Comment: El error no esta dento de `.front > img {`, al parecer esta por `.card > .front, .card > .back {` y en `border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;` puede usarlo asi: `border-radius: 1rem;`

Comment: @Sebastian, pues el resultado es el mismo con el cambio que me indicas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fijate si asi esta bien?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  background: #DDDFE2; }

section {
  background: 100%;
  height: 400px; }
.main_bus {
  background-size: 30%;
  position: relative; }
  .main_bus .layout_center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left: 80px;
    width: calc(100% - (70px + 70px)); }
    .flex_content {
            display: flex; }

          .flex_column {
            flex: 1;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            padding: .4em; }
            .flex_column img {
              padding-top: .4em; }
            .flex_column div {
              padding-top: .4em; }
          .height_250px{
            height: 250px;
          }
          .height_350px{
            height: 350px;
          }
          .height_270px{
            height: 270px;
          }
          .height_450px{
            height: 450px;
          }
          .height_300px{
            height: 300px;
          }
          .height_560px{
            height: 560px;
          }
          .card{
            background: transparent;
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
            
          }
          .card > .front,
          .card > .back {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            position: absolute;
            transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
            transition-duration: 1s;
            transition-property: transform, opacity;
            border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
            background:red;
            padding: 0;
          }
          .front{
            top:0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 1;
          }
          .front > img{
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: block;
            border-radius: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
            padding: 0;
          }
          .back{
            background: #fcfabc;
            top:0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
            transform: rotateY(-180deg);
          }
          .card:hover > .front {
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
            opacity: 0;
          }
          .card:hover > .back {
            opacity: 1;
            transform: rotateY(0deg);
          }
```

```html
<section class="main_bus" id="inicio">
            
            <div class="layout_center">
                <div class="flex_content">
                  <div class="flex_column">
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_560px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/9a/a9/f0/9aa9f0235a64eb5f123402efcacb5197.jpg" alt="">  
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_270px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/fa/84/09/fa840965a10cb0c28410d06e5087978a.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_250px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/e9/2b/c3/e92bc328087ee008adf4eee9411e8a4c.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_300px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/93/8f/56/938f564ca79e20fe54cb42df44b1c150.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex_column">
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_250px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6c/61/d2/6c61d2afbe1551435f2e858365465cbd.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_350px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/8c/fa/06/8cfa06657b77435e91c3466f15319ebb.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_450px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/3a/a8/51/3aa8513f2d9fde7a97e83a891aa64a73.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <div class="card height_270px">
                        <div class="front">
                          <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/564x/ed/00/75/ed0075587fdeeed877c0aab2a23572c5.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="back">
                          atras
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  

                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

**ACTUALIZADO**

Lo que hice fue agregar un `padding: 0;` sobre las clases `.card > .front, .card > .back` y `.front > img{` que tu habias nombrado!

```
      .card > .front,
      .card > .back {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: absolute;
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
        transition-duration: 1s;
        transition-property: transform, opacity;
        border-radius: 25px; // tambien puede usarlo asi
        background:red;
        padding: 0; //padding 0
      }

      .front > img{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
        border-radius: 25px; // tambien puede usarlo asi
        padding: 0; //padding 0
      }
```

Comment: Pues se ve bien, podrias especificar que es lo que cambiaste?

Comment: Ya esta actualizado!